# which one is onto function?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

let $A= \{x^2 \mid 0 < x <1\}$ and $B =\{x^3 \mid 1 < x < 2 \}$.

Which of the statement is true?

1.there is a one to one, onto function from $A$ to $B$.

2.there is no onto function from $A$ to $B$

my attempt ; there will be no onto function from $A$ to $B$ because  order  of $A$ is $2$ and order $B$ is $3$ so  there is no one one function from $A$ to $B$.

So my answer is option 2,,
is my answer is correct or not ...pliz tell me the solution

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$
B=(1,2^3)=(1,8)\\
A=(0,1)
$$
Then, take 
$$
f:A\to B\\
f(x)=7x+1
$$
which is linear and thus invertible.

Comment: thanks,,,,, @qbert

Comment: Nice! Now I feel silly for using a cardinality argument.

Comment: @JohnGriffin no biggie, good way to see it instantly!

Answer (score 1):

"...because the order of $A$ is $2$ and the order of $B$ is $3$, so..."
What do you mean by the order of a set? How does this relate to the functions it admits?

Note that $A=(0,1)$ and $B=(1,8)$. Both of these sets have the same cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$. Thus there are bijections $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$ and $g:B\to\mathbb{R}$. Using $f$ and $g$, can you construct a bijection from $A$ onto $B$?

Comment: thanks a lots @ john Griffin  now i understand...